# Spring Boot Flyway AutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

Hy,

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.7RELEASE with Flyway 4.2.0.
I have a problem with the configuration of the *flyway.locations* property for file system locations.

If I use *file:* prefix, I have Flyway error:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unknown prefix for location (should be either filesystem: or classpath:):
```

If I use *filesystem:* prefix, I have

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find migrations location in:
```

What am I doing wrong ? (If I use *classpath:* everything is ok)

Comment: Can you post your configuration?  Also, is there any reason why you are not using the default version of flyway (3.2.1) for spring boot 1.5.7.RELEASE?    https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with FlywayAutoConfiguration in Spring Boot.

A workaround is to use the `filesystem:` prefix but disable location checking:

```
spring.flyway.check-location=false # spring boot 2.0.x
flyway.check-location=false        # spring boot 1.5.x
```

I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13862) and submitted a [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/13863).

---

### Update

The fix was merged into Spring Boot [1.5.15](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/114?closed=1) and 2.0.4.